# Passing parent model's id to child's new and create action on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My project has 2 models, Company and Product. Company has many products and products belongs to company. I want to put a link to Product's new action on a Company show page and pass company_id to Product new action so that the new product automatically belongs to the company from which it linked.

How should I change below codes to make this happen?
My environment is ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.2

**show.html.erb(Companies)**

```
<%= link_to "Add new product", new_product_path(company_id: @company) %>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def new
@product = Product.new(params[:company_id])
end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params, params[:company_id])
    if @product.save
        flash[:success] = "Product successfully created."
        redirect_to @product
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**new.html.erb(products)**

```
<% provide(:title, 'New product') %>
<h1>Add a new product</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

            <%= f.label :name, "Product Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :description, "Description" %>
            <%= f.text_area :description %>

            <%= f.label :type, "Product Type" %>
            <%= f.text_field :type %>

            <%= f.label :released_date, "Released Date" %>
            <%= f.date_field :released_date %>

            #I want to omit below 2 lines by passing company_id from company show action
            <%= f.label :company_id, "Company ID" %> 
            <%= f.text_field :company_id %>

            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

:comapny_id is passed to product new action as shown in URL.

```
http://localhost:3000/products/new?company_id=6
```

Also shown in debug log.

```
company_id: '6'
action: new
controller: products
```

Comment: We're missing 1) Error output 2) params output 3) models 4) HTML form output

Comment: Apologies for a lack of explanation. It doesn't produce an error, but when a new product is created, :company_id is empty and thus does not belong to the company. Product's create action should automatically inherit :company_id passed along from company page so that user does not have to input :company_id.
With current code, a product is successfully created but missing  :company_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error lies in the way you create the new product in the new action. At the moment it only passes the company id itself to the constructor, but you are not telling rails wich property should be set with it.

If you change it to `@product = Product.new(company_id: params[:company_id])`, then your new product object should have the company id and it should be filled in in the create form. Then, instead of omitting the fields you could just use a hidden field. Like this, there is no extra field for the company_id but it is still automatically added to the product_params and `@product = Product.new(product_params)` will create a product with a company_id.