# How to create new records with nested attributes in a ruby on rails "has many through" relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I need some advice on building a has many through relationship between USER, THING and EXTRA models.

My USER model is slightly modified inside Devise gem and is noted as Creator whereas other models belonging to USER receive :created_things form.

In my app, USERS create THINGS can later add EXTRAS to their THINGS.

I chose has many through because I want to have unique data on all three models and be able to call both THINGS and EXTRAS from the USER "CREATOR" model.

I have built this many different ways and after 10 years of solving my problems by reading stackoverflow, I am finally submitting this request for support! Thank you for your help.

I have tried creating user and extra references on the THING model and declaring nested attributes in the USER and THING model. I have tried several examples from stackoverflow inside the create and new methods but nothing seems to work.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :created_things, class_name: Thing, foreign_key: 
:creator_id, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :extras, through: :created_things
accepts_nested_attributes_for :extras, :reject_if => :all_blank, 
allow_destroy: true

class Thing < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :creator, class_name: User 
has_many :extras
accepts_nested_attributes_for :extras, :reject_if => :all_blank, 
allow_destroy: true

class Extra < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :creator, class_name: User, inverse_of: :thing
belongs_to :created_things

Members Index.html.erb
<% if thing.extras.exists? %>
<% thing.extras.each do |extra| %>
<%= extra.title %> <%= link_to "[+]", edit_extra_path(extra) %>
<% end %>
<% else if thing.extras.empty? %>
<%= link_to "+1 EXTRA", new_extra_path(current_user) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

class MembersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
@user = current_user
@created_extras = @user.extras
@created_things = @user.created_things
end

class ExtrasController < ApplicationController
def new
@extra = Extra.new
end

def create
@extra = current_user.extras.build(extra_params)
if @extra.save
```

I am able to create a new EXTRA but the :thing_id remains nul as it does not display when called on the show extra view. Therefore I am not surprised that when I return to the member index page that my thing.extras.exists? call is returning false and the created extra never displays under the THING view. My attempts to modify the extra controller have failed and I some of my reading sugested the extras controller is not necessary in this relationship so I am really at a loss on how this is built.  I'm assuming I am missing something in new and create methods maybe in things or user controller? Perhaps I'm missing something in routes resources? Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I really didn't need has many through for this model and I did a lot of testing of the syntax on each model.rb and in the end was able to figure it out from this stackoverflow . . .

[[Passing parent model's id to child's new and create action on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531109/passing-parent-models-id-to-childs-new-and-create-action-on-rails][1])

Here are my the various parts of setting up a has many and belongs to relationship with nested attributes.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :creator, class_name: User
has_many :extras, inverse_of: :thing, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :extras, allow_destroy: true

class Extra < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :thing, inverse_of: :extras
```

**extras_controller.rb**

```
 class ExtrasController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @extra = Extra.new(thing_id: params[:thing_id])
 end

  def create

    @user = current_user
    @extra = Extra.new(extra_params)
    @extra.user_id = @user.id

      if @extra.save
      flash[:success] = "You have added a new Extra!"
      redirect_to @extra #extras_path later
    else
      flash[:danger] = "The form contains errors"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**edit.html.erb things**

```
<% if @thing.extras.exists? %>
<p>current extras associated with <%= @thing.title %>: </p>
<% @thing.extras.each do |extra| %>
<p><%= extra.title %> <%= link_to "[+]", edit_extra_path(extra) %> 
/ <%= link_to "[-]", extra_path(extra), method: :delete %> </p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "+1 EXTRA", new_extra_path(thing_id: @thing.id) %>

<%= render 'things/form' %>
```